# Many lights with shadows in three.js causes Fragment shader error

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

Assume to have a scene with a street with many streetlights (more 20), you move an object close by them and you expect a shadow.

The lights, simply

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5, 6.0);
```

Only the street has `.receiveShadow = true` and only the car has `.castShadow = true` (besides later the lights)

[image: example]

In three.js adding `.castShadow = true` to all of the lights causes following error

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false 
gl.getProgramInfoLog Fragment shader sampler count exceeds MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS (16).
```

Luckily in hour scene we only need a few (at max 4) of them to cast a shadow, as most of the lights are out of reach anyway.

I tried to use 2 approaches

1. Looping through all the lights and setting `.castShadow = true` or `.castShadow = false` dynamically.
2. Adding and removing the lights completely but setting them with no shadow or a shadow.

With both of them I got the same error.

What other approach would work?

## Update

@neeh created a Fiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ro8j7z4z/1/) (to cause the error change `var numLightRows = 8;` to a higher number). Keep an eye on the error though, there will be another error with too many lights that isn't caused by the same problem

He also pointed out that we see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/shadowmap_pars_fragment.glsl) that a `pointShadowMap` is created even when not in use. This explains why there is no change with a "smarter" approach. This now is within the GLSL code.

So we are limited by the GPU, which in my case has 16 IMAGE_UNITS but that isn't the case for all GPUs (my CPU actually works fine with more). You can check on your system with `renderer.capabilities.maxTextures`. But as mentioned we really only need 4.

The problem remains.

Comment: I would not use `scene.remove( light )` and `scene.add( light )` but traverse the scene for lights, remove their shadows and for the ones that are close to the car turn them on.

Comment: @gaitat I tried both and sadly both alternatives failed

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

Yes <s>a [new **shadow map** will be created](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLShadowMap.js#L190) for every light having `castShadow = true`</s> **(Actually, this is not the case, check [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11035))**. A shadow map is a drawn on which a shadow is computed in order to be blended on a surface afterwards.

> gl.getProgramInfoLog Fragment shader sampler count exceeds MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS (16).

It means that your device can send **no more than 16 textures per draw call**. Typically, the car (street?) on which you'd like to put shadows is 1 draw call.

To draw a object that receives shadows, **all the shadow maps should be blended** together with the diffuse map. So this requires to use *N+1* texture units for one single draw call. (*N* being the number of lights that can cast shadow.)

If you dig into Three.js shaders, you'd find [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/shadowmap_pars_fragment.glsl) :

```
#ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP

    #if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0

        // Reserving NUM_DIR_LIGHTS texture units
        uniform sampler2D directionalShadowMap[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];
        varying vec4 vDirectionalShadowCoord[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];

    #endif

    ...

#endif
```

Check [this tool](https://browserleaks.com/webgl) to see how much texture units your browser can handle (*Fragment shader* > *Max Texture Image Units*).

---

## The solution ?

Dynamically creating and deleting lights is bad because it's memory-intensive (allocation of a shadow map...).

But, as [gaitat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980846/gaitat) said, you can enable shadows **only for the nearest lights**. Just do the following in your render loop :

1. Disable all shadows: `light.castShadow = false;`
2. Seek nearest lights
3. Enable shadow for *N* nearest lights: `light.castShadow = true;`

### Improvement

This algorithm lonely is bad because it allocates one shadow map per light. In addition to be memory-consuming, the rendering would freeze for a bit every time you cross a new light that has no shadow map allocated...

Hence, the idea is to **reuse** the same shadows maps for the nearest lights. You can deal with shadow maps like this :

```
// create a new shadow map
var shadowMapCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1, 0.5, 500);
var shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(shadowMapCamera);

// use the shadow map on a light
light.shadow = shadow;
shadow.camera.position.copy(light.position);
light.castShadow = true;
```

You can get the maximum number of texture units with `renderer.capabilities.maxTextures`. So you can compute the number of shadow map to create based on it but remember to leave some for more regular maps like diffuseMap, normalMap...

[image]

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro8j7z4z/1/) for a full implementation (only 4 shadow maps are used).

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answer, it certainly gave me some insight. Unforgenetly it doesn't solve the issue. Increasing `numLightRows` causes the error again. It seems strange, you can add as many lights as you'd like without a problem, but just adding a single shadow light will cause it to fail.

Comment: That's strange, I don't have this error, even with 100 lights and `maxTextures = 32`. Well actually I got another error but that's because I have too much lights in my scene. Are you sure it's the exact same error?

Comment: Yes, same error with up to 29 lights, after I get the same error as on my notebook: `Varyings over maximum register limit`, but I know that this is a hardware limit, so nothing to do there. I have an EVGA 970 is that's a concern.

Comment: So the `Fragment shader sampler count exceeds MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS (16)` error still starts with 16 lights? That would means there's another per-light map somewhere.

Comment: I think I got another idea that should work for any number of lights, if I succeed I would write a new answer.

Comment: Could be. Basically, I can add as many lights as I want. But as soon as one has a shadow, it crashes. Sure, glad I get some help here

Comment: Yes, just realized that... I don't see why.

Comment: Oh I got it! Just look at the code I pasted, `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;` activates `USE_SHADOWMAP` and then we're allocating `NUM_POINTS_LIGHTS` varying! So the engine doesn't even care about how many shadow maps we're sending... Anyway, I have a new idea and imma delete this answer.